# Extracting entire column of data from a grid not necessarily HTML but an AgGrid into array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Could not find a clear explanation of how to achieve this. Does JS have a straight forward method for taking the entire column from a grid and populating an array with one cell value per array element. I do know the value of each cell. But I want to make an array of all the individual cell values. I am relatively new to JS and thought it might be wiser to ask here than to go on mashing code together seeing no results.
Thank you so much, Luxy

For example,

```
 My cell value is in params.data["Bug Feature"] // which prints each value 0, 13, text, text, 0...
```

What I want is to make an array of the single values to an array.

I didn't mean to get a full implementation. I just wanted to know the right way. This is what I am doing currently. But it is making each cell value an array which is not what I am looking for.

```
  var sortBUGFeatures = jQuery.makeArray(params.data["Bug Feature"]);
```

i did it in jQuery but I thought JS would be little simpler for me

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for implementation.

Comment: I didn't mean to get a full implementation. I just wanted to know the right way. I have posted my working now. But wanted to know the right way of doing it

Comment: An array of arrays? I am unable to reproduce that from your original statement that data only has an array in it. For example, this `jQuery.makeArray([0,13,12,12,0]);` results in `[0,13,12,12,0]`

Comment: Yes, it only makes array of the individual cell value. But I want to make array of the whole column

Comment: What you are trying to do is not clear from your example attempt and shown values. Please edit in a more verbose and reproducible example that demonstrates the issue you are facing.